# Calculation on the squashed entanglement

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, topological-insulators

The definition of squashed entanglement:[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashed_entanglement)

I read a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.13805) on this topic, and found a good result (Fig.2(a)) from it showing that the squashed entropy can indicate topological phase transition of SSH model and seems to converge quicker than von Neumann entropy. But how can I compute this entropy? The infimum in its definition is quite confusing. Is it possible to compute it through correlation matrix method?

Comment: All plots in the paper only show either mutual informations or negativity, which don't require any minimization/maximization process. It is likely that the authors don't know how to compute squashed entanglement either:)

Comment: @MengCheng Alright, so the QCMI they computed was still based on the ground-state correlation matrix method.

Comment: Out of all entanglement measures, most of which are extremely hard to calculate, squashed entanglement is among the worst.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I see. Is there any other computable entanglement besides von Neumann and Renyi?

Comment: I assume we are talking about ent. measures for *mixed* states. In that case, Neumann/Renyi entropies are *not* a good measure. If you want sth. computable: Negativity, as already the title of the original paper says.

Comment: recent related twitter by Mark Wilde: https://twitter.com/markwilde/status/1560381076740182017. Figuring out whether squashed entanglement is computable is cited as one of the "biggest open questions in quantum informatoin". Just as a piece of informal "evidence" of how little we know how to compute Squashed entanglement yet.

Comment: @glS This list is of course very subjective and centered on information theory in the narrow sense. Also, I'm not 100% sure what is meant by "computable", probably in the halting problem sense. -- The key issue with squashed entanglement is that it involves the minimization of a quantity over (mixed) extensions of the state, and it is not known whether the dimension of this extension is bounded; unlike for instance for ent. of formation, which is also a hard optimization but at least in fixed dimension. -- On the other hand, I believe the same problem holds for a number of other ...

Comment: ... ent. measures, such as regularized ones (entanglement cost), or distillable entanglement (could be seen as "implicitly regularized"). What is maybe remarkable is that squashed ent. does not contain such a regularization, yet there is no bound on the size of the optimization problem. (Then again, it has been explicitly constructed to be additive -- that's a (the?) key point -- so it is equal to its regularization, and it is not entirely surprising that the difficulty from regularization is hiding somewhere else.)